# Get every X item from Realm results?

Tags: swift, swift3, realm, nspredicate, predicate

I am querying large result sets from Realm, between 50-100K items. I need to graph this, but is unnecessary to use the full set. I'd like to decimate by getting every 20 items from the result set.

Is there a predicate that can do this, instead of looping through one-by-one and picking every X item to build a new array?

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1580 , although you can try [this answer](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2608#issuecomment-242714265) but considering I don't actually know Swift, I can't tell if it's good or bad.